# AngularJS Cookies - Cookies saved in Browser but not displaying

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I have injected the cookies and i am saving the value in cookies like this,

```
$cookies.name = "Alfred";
console.log("cookie " +$cookies.name);
```

and in HTML i display

```
{{name}}
```

the cookies are getting saved and displayed in console, But in HTML it is not getting displayed. I have checked the chrome browser too, the cookies are saved in localhost..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have a scope variable to display it

```
$cookies.name = "Alfred";
$scope.cookiname = $cookies.name ;
```

In HTML

```
<div>Name: {{cookiname}}</div>
```

Here is the [`working App`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/71p2aLm9/3/)

Comment: When i assign, $scope.cookiname = $cookies.name, in console.log, it says undefined..

Comment: you need to add the $cookies as a dependency to the controller,check the jsfiddle i have added